# How to package Next.js application as a reusable Node library?

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

I have built a `next.js` application with some bare minimum functionality that includes:

- Middleware for authentication
- Protected file serving api routes
- Logging for error handling

Now I want to publish this as an npm module and allow other teams to build their own pages/views on top of this. How to bundle and publish this `next.js` application as a library?

Answer (score 0):

I was designing the production application and instead of making a publishable module from the `next.js` app I designed functional workspace packages which are publishable and reuse them in the other `next.js` applications.

[using-npm/workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces)

I would not recommend to make a npm module from the `next.js` self, because it will appear in the module dependencies (unless you'll set it as a peer dependency).
I think this kind of approach may limit future progress as you may need to support another non `next.js` project.
(Maybe I'm talking bananas here, but this arose in my head during answering :)

Or perhaps you wanted to make a [template application](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-a-template-repository) containing your basic functionality?
Also the [yeoman.io](https://yeoman.io/learning/index.html) can help in this case.

This question lead me to think how to package the `next.js` application and use it as some single file app. And I found [this nice solution](https://medium.com/@evenchange4/deploy-a-commercial-next-js-application-with-pkg-and-docker-5c73d4af2ee). I'm placing it here for future reference, but I understand it is not a core of your question.

Answer (score -2):

You can use github with npm registry to publish your package.
[Github packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/publishing-a-package)
[npm registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry)

Comment: It is not about using `npm` or `github` registry. It is about packaging compiled Next.js app as a reusable library.